# локальная база данных C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

В чем моя ошибка?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Мои документы\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BLR\BLR\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableStudents VALUES (@Name, @Education)";
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", 1);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", 2);
        //com.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO TableStudents (Name, Education)");
        //com.Parameters.Add("Name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        //com.Parameters.Add("Education", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
         temp = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
    return temp;
}
```

при команде `SELECT` данная конструкция работает, с `INSERT` ни в какую... что делать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `INSERT INTO [TableStudents] (Name, Education) VALUES (@Name, @Education)` попробуйте

Comment: Так как вы вставлять иногда можно, но к-во столбцов и типы столбцов должны совпадать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не прописываете столбцы, а только значения. Смотрите ответ вопроса [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956533/sql-insert-query-using-c-sharp).

Comment: делаю так                   
`string query = "INSERT INTO TableStudents (Name,Education) VALUES (@Name, @Education)";
                    
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", 1);
                    comm.Parameters.Add("@Education", 2);
                    temp = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`
результата нет